# Specify nested (object)s in Blueprint?

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io, apiary

*My nested-object Attribute shows no errors/warnings, but doesn't display usefully in apiary.io. What am I doing wrong?*

I have a structure (response body) like this:

`{
  "f1": "v1",
  "f2": "v2",
  "f3": {
    "f3f1": "v3v1",
    "f3f2": "v3v2"
  }
}`

As I read the several specs, this should be described as

`+ Attributes
    - f1: v1
    - f2: v2
    - f3
      - f3f1: v3v1
      - f3f2: v3v2`

and apiary.io should show a table that (among other things) displays all four example values.

But the resulting table doesn't mention the sub-object.

Can this be done (is it supported  yet)? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, MSON support in Apiary is still in beta stage. We (Apiary) are working on a nice and interactive interface for it. Please look at https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/issues/191 for more information.

Thanks.